# Omit one of the many where conditions if a constant is a specific value

Tags: python, sql, pandas, replace, pyodbc

I am pulling records from a SQL Server from python:

```
REGION = 'HK'
.
.
    where   

                R.rfq_create_date_time >= '""" + START_DATE + """'
                and R.rfq_create_date_time <= '""" + END_DATE + """'
                and R.latest_version = 'Y' 
                and R.sales_book in ('""" + sales_code_string + """')
                and R.Trading_book in ('""" + Trading_Books + """')
                ) as innerTable 
                WHERE rfq_create_time not between '""" + START_TIME + """' and '""" + END_TIME + """'
                order by rfq_create_time"""

    print (strSql)
    print("")
    df_With_NaN = pd.read_sql(strSql, pyodbc.connect(connstr))
```

I only want the `and R.Trading_book in` condition included in the string to pass to my connection if `REGION` is HK or SY. In the case of TK I want the condition ignored all together.

Is the replace method the best way to do this in python or is there an alterantive? For example:

```
REGION = "TK"
strsql = "select * from table where ccy = 'AAA' ######"
if REGION == "HK":
    booklist = "'AAA','BBB','CCC'"
elif REGION == "SY":
    booklist = "'CCC','DDD','FFF'"

if REGION == "TK":
    strsql = strsql.replace("######", "")
else:
    strsql = strsql.replace("######", " and book in (" + booklist + ")")

print (strsql)
```

Comment: You might be interested in using a templating language (like https://github.com/hashedin/jinjasql) to create the sql in a more readable and maintainable fashion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative which might be slightly more readable would be

```python
if REGION == "HK":
    booklist = "'AAA','BBB','CCC'"
elif REGION == "SY":
    booklist = "'CCC','DDD','FFF'"
else:
    booklist = ""
booklist_clause = "AND book IN ({})".format(booklist) if booklist else ""
strsql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ccy = 'AAA' {}".format(booklist_clause)
```

or, if you are using Python 3.6 or later you could do

```python
booklist_clause = f"AND book IN ({booklist})" if booklist else ""
strsql = f"SELECT * FROM table WHERE ccy = 'AAA' {booklist_clause}"
```

Comment: Thanks @Gord Thompson, I had no idea about F strings in python. This is very useful!!